# Why is DirectMethodHandle$Holder not a member class of DirectMethodHandle, according to reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotation-processing

Consider the [`DirectMethodHandle$Holder` class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-19+36/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/DirectMethodHandle.java#L938).  (It is one of the classes returned by `Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle").getDeclaredClasses()`, which is [documented to return member classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses()).)

The following assertion fails under JDK 19:

```
assert Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder").isMemberClass();
```

Why? Which [rule of section 8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5) does it violate?

Like some of the commenters, I am coming to the conclusion that this is a very weird bug.  For example, using some `javax.annotation.processing` and some `javax.lang.model.*` classes, the following assertion does not fail:

```
assert NestingKind.MEMBER == ((TypeElement)processingEnvironment.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.Holder")).getNestingKind();
```

So the outputs of the mechanisms underpinning the compiler do not agree with the outputs of the reflection machinery. I've [filed a bug against the JDK](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8300181).

Comment: It looks like a bug but maybe they are going to explain why it's not if you open a bug report.

Comment: But this begs the question: what are you actually trying to achieve with this?  (Apart from trying to see if it ... erm ... works.)

Comment: It was a class encountered during some reflection-based traversal of `String.clasd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Holger already said, the class file does not correspond to the source code. This class file is overwritten with a different one by a jlink plugin that runs when the JDK is created.

[There are several such holder classes in the jdk](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/754f6e6116b8889c49abf34d01f6fc3e9f1b3cb7/src/jdk.jlink/share/classes/jdk/tools/jlink/internal/plugins/GenerateJLIClassesPlugin.java#L157-L164):

```
private static final String DIRECT_METHOD_HOLDER_ENTRY =
        "/java.base/java/lang/invoke/DirectMethodHandle$Holder.class";
private static final String DELEGATING_METHOD_HOLDER_ENTRY =
        "/java.base/java/lang/invoke/DelegatingMethodHandle$Holder.class";
private static final String BASIC_FORMS_HOLDER_ENTRY =
        "/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaForm$Holder.class";
private static final String INVOKERS_HOLDER_ENTRY =
        "/java.base/java/lang/invoke/Invokers$Holder.class";
```

These hold the contents of certain pre-generated `java.lang.invoke` implementation classes. Pre-generating these classes during jlink-time avoids having to generate them at runtime. So, this is essentially done for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind, that you are looking at very special code for Java/JVM interaction. You get a hint when looking at the comment right before the source code:

```java
/* Placeholder class for DirectMethodHandles generated ahead of time */
final class Holder {}
```

<sup>emphasis on “placeholder” and “generated”</sup>

When I run `jdk-17\bin\javap java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder`, I get the following output:

```java
final class java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder {
  static int invokeInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, double);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int, int);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, int);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, long);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, long);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, int);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, long);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static int invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void invokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int invokeSpecialIFC(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int invokeSpecialIFC(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, double, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, double);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, double);
  static int invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, int, int, int);
  static int invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, int, int);
  static int invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, int);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, int);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, int);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, long);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object);
  static long invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, long);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static int invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(java.lang.Object);
  static void invokeStatic(java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeStaticInit(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void invokeVirtual(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object invokeVirtual(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, int, int);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, int);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object newInvokeSpecial(java.lang.Object);
  static int getBoolean(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int getBooleanVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putBoolean(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putBooleanVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getBoolean(java.lang.Object);
  static int getBooleanVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putBoolean(java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putBooleanVolatile(java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getByte(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int getByteVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putByte(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putByteVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getByte(java.lang.Object);
  static int getByteVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putByte(java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putByteVolatile(java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getShort(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int getShortVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putShort(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putShortVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getShort(java.lang.Object);
  static int getShortVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putShort(java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putShortVolatile(java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getChar(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int getCharVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putChar(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putCharVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getChar(java.lang.Object);
  static int getCharVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putChar(java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putCharVolatile(java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getInt(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static int getIntVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putInt(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putIntVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, int);
  static int getInt(java.lang.Object);
  static int getIntVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putInt(java.lang.Object, int);
  static void putIntVolatile(java.lang.Object, int);
  static long getLong(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static long getLongVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putLong(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static void putLongVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, long);
  static long getLong(java.lang.Object);
  static long getLongVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putLong(java.lang.Object, long);
  static void putLongVolatile(java.lang.Object, long);
  static float getFloat(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static float getFloatVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putFloat(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, float);
  static void putFloatVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, float);
  static float getFloat(java.lang.Object);
  static float getFloatVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putFloat(java.lang.Object, float);
  static void putFloatVolatile(java.lang.Object, float);
  static double getDouble(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static double getDoubleVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putDouble(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, double);
  static void putDoubleVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, double);
  static double getDouble(java.lang.Object);
  static double getDoubleVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putDouble(java.lang.Object, double);
  static void putDoubleVolatile(java.lang.Object, double);
  static java.lang.Object getReference(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object getReferenceVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putReference(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putReferenceVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object getReference(java.lang.Object);
  static java.lang.Object getReferenceVolatile(java.lang.Object);
  static void putReference(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  static void putReferenceVolatile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
}
```

which is a strong hint that the class is not the one you get by compiling the empty one-line definition. It seems that the generator for this actual class file did not care to produce an equivalent [`InnerClasses` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6) for the replacement class file. Since this attribute has no impact on the actual execution of the code, it shouldn’t matter.

So there’s no bug, neither in the compiler nor reflections, the mismatch is caused by the fact that the class does not originate from the source code.

Comment: Yes, I understand it is very special. I guess I still do not understand why the reflection model and the language model differ in their outputs, or rather, why that's OK.

Comment: Reflection only tells you what it found in the class file. As said, the class file has been replaced at some point between source code compilation and JDK deployment. It’s ok here, because there was no need for an inner class to begin with. It’s not used as an inner class. It’s, as the name suggests, just a placeholder. And an implementation detail.